# I am trying to get different output(with apostrophes)

Tags: python

I AM TRYING TO OUTPUT THIS:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

But the output i get is

```
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
```

mine output has any apostrophe both sides like string type ('str')

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def commaCode(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        str(x[i])
        str(print(str(x[i]),end = ', '))
    str(print( 'and '+str(x[-1])))
commaCode(spam)
```

Comment: Oh i am new in programming and the book i am currently reading says output should have apostrophes.Thank You for the information

Comment: You don't need the loop, use `join`: `print(', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ' and ' + spam[-1])`

Comment: Are you simply missing a `'` from the beginning and end of your output? You could add them in by calling `print("'", end='')` at the start and finish of your function

Comment: I don`t know the join statement I am just finished chapter 4 in automatetheboringstuffwithPython book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple modification of your code:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def commaCode(x):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        result = result + x[i] + ', '
    result = result + 'and ' + x[-1]

    print("'" + result + "'")

commaCode(spam)

#output: 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use join method too :

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def commaCode(x):
    return "'"+', '.join(spam)+"'"
print(commaCode(spam))
```

OUTPUT:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, cats'
```